# Reading Mi Yodeya in the bathroom

Tags: halacha, torah-study, bathroom, stackexchange

Is it ok to open Mi Yodeya in the bathroom and skim through the questions trying to find ones that aren't really included in limud ha'torah in order to read them? Or is the opening of the app and the skimming the questions in the bathroom  already included in degradation of words of Torah?

Comment: One may not disrespect the Torah. However, respect and disrespect cant be quantified (since they are defined by context; not he mere act). Assuming that no prohibited content is studied, only you can know whether this is degrading. | You (almost certainly) wont find a halakhic source stating whether or not "opening an app that includes some Torah content" is considered disrespectful.

Comment: Accordingly, this seems most probably opinion based.

Comment: @mevaqesh , you would be surprised

Comment: @sam I agree. If I were incorrect, I would be surprised; by definition. If I would expect to be incorrect, then I evidently never held a position in the first place. | Regarding the case at hand, even were a source to be found, I suspect it would nevertheless amount to just the opinion of that author, for the reason I specified. | Do you have some evidence or arguments to the contrary? If not, then your comment seems fairly useless.

Comment: I came across a Shu"t which discusses texting in bathroom ,it had a lot of info have to remember which one it was ,and your commnet of almost certainty that one will not find such a Shu"t is also quite useless,since there are modern Shu"t which discuss an array of topics one wouldnt believe exist

Comment: You seem to be completely missing the point of my comments. I recommend you read them again @sam. Remember: to ping other users use the @

Comment: @sam yes, some bathrooms are congruent with the cheder Haemtsay or Hachitsoni of bet hamerchats,

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?cat=437

Comment: If you assume that current bathrooms meat the definition of *bet hakisseh* (there's a debate on that), then, it is pretty clear that many of the questions on this site contain words of Torah, so reading those questions would probably be prohibited. If you want to be "safe", I would stick with the questions that get closed because they don't deal with Judaism. It's not a guarantee, but many of them don't dsicuss Torah. You have a number of non-closed questions like that on this site, also. I won't create a bias by mentioning any, in particular ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't scrolling through the questions trigger Torah thoughts? Definitely "pastnisht"

Answer (score 2):

The real issue I would worry about when scrolling through a list of MY questions is the interdiction of thinking thoughts of Torah in a bathroom. Even if our current-day bathrooms are not the *bet hakissei* of halacha (there is some discussion on this, see e.g., beginning of [this](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/224278/halachically-speaking-halachos-regarding-the-bathroom.html)), the Mishne Torah ([Laws of Shema 3:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Reading_the_Shema.3.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) and Shulchan Aruch ([OH 85:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.85.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) forbid thoughts of Torah in a place where there is urine or feces.

Says the Rambam

> Even to meditate silently on the words of the Torah in a latrine, in a
>   bath house, or in any unclean place that contains ordure or urine, is
>   also prohibited.

Bringing a phone with "electronic words of Torah" is not an issue since "electronic words" do not have the status of a Torah text, see e.g., [here](http://dinonline.org/2014/02/04/taking-tablet-into-bathroom/).

**Bottom line as long as one is using the bathroom, it is NOT a good idea to review MY questions unless one is completely sure this will not evoke thoughts of Torah.**

Comment: I'm really uncertain how one could avoid doing your **bold** suggestion.

Comment: @DanF of course. I agree. But if I had not written this, people would have said "what if I read MY without thinking of Torah" :-> So better safe than sorry !

Comment: I got your motive. But, it's impossible to contradict a tautology.