# Facebooking in the bathroom

Tags: technology, bathroom, social-media

It is forbidden to think, speak or read words of Torah while using the bathroom as per Shulchan Aruch O:C 85:2 [based on Shabbos 40b]

If a person is using the bathroom and they know that from time to time pesukim or other Torah related materials show up in their Facebook feed (or similar social feed apps) are they allowed to browse Facebook at that time?

If the answer is yes and some Torah related material does show up what is the best course of action? Scroll past it or close the phone?

Comment: On a side note, I don't think it's a great idea to surf your phone in the bathroom anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Mi Yodeya in the bathroom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78916/reading-mi-yodeya-in-the-bathroom)

Comment: @DonielF I don't see how that's a duplicate. This question is asking whether one could look at a non-Torah oriented website out of a fear that you might read something Torah oriented (unless the answer to that question is that it's permitted to read something Torah-oriented in the bathroom, in which case Kal Vachomer something not Torah-oriented that may occasionally have Torah in it would be permitted) .

Comment: @Salmononius2 Read that question again, which specifically asks about skipping the Torah questions and looking at the non-Torah questions. How is this different, given that in the OP there’s an explicit concern for Torah popping up in the feed? To the contrary, I’d think *this* is worse, because on MY you’d have to click on the question to see the actual Torah, whereas there it’s already on the main page.

Comment: Actually, one should avoid Facebook in any event. It is not a proper site to go to and can be dangerous.